# Add to Google Calendar render link not showing user's local time

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, google-calendar-api

I am able to create an event using this link to google calendar.
but time is coming as UTC i think (its 5.30 hours ahead the time I wanted on event)

Example:
[This link](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit?dates=20210430T123000/20210430T160000&location=Calgary,%20Downtown&text=The%202020%20Festival) will create an event but it shows time from 12.30pm to 4pm.
This event supposed to be 6.30am to 10am.

[According to this link](https://github.com/InteractionDesignFoundation/add-event-to-calendar-docs/blob/master/services/google.md), removing Z from time string should set user's local time in event.

> to use the user's timezone: 20201231T193000/20201231T223000 (don't specify a timezone);

> to use UTC timezone, convert datetime to UTC, then use Z suffix: 20201231T193000Z/20201231T223000Z;

I have also tried the same solution from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549128/link-to-add-and-save-event-in-google-calendar) but still event time is not coming as it. its getting converted in the link.

```
const startDateTimeFormattedGoogle = eventStartDateTime ? eventStartDateTime.format(
        "YYYYMMDDTHHmmss"
      ) : null;
      const endDateTimeFormattedGoogle = eventEndDateTime ? eventEndDateTime.format(
        "YYYYMMDDTHHmmss"
      ) : null;
      const addToGoogleLink = `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&dates=${startDateTimeFormattedGoogle}/${endDateTimeFormattedGoogle}&location=${data.location}&text=${data.title}`;
```

Update:

```
console.log(88888, moment(eventStartDateTime).format('YYYYMMDDTHHmmssZ'),
result: 88888 20210430T123000+00:00 20210430T160000+00:00

console.log(111111, moment(eventStartDateTime).format('YYYYMMDDTHHmmss'),
        moment(eventEndDateTime).format('YYYYMMDDTHHmmss'))
result : 111111 20210430T123000 20210430T160000

result url: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&dates=20210430T123000+00:00/20210430T160000+00:00&location=Calgary, Downtown&text=The 2020 Festival
```

Comment: oh i see so does it mean if I provide Z, it will convert for the user's time zone? am i getting it right?

Comment: not sure whats going on with this. I have added Z and removed it. I updated the question with latest finding. time on my node js server prints the same time regardless of timezone. also the final url on client machine shows same time all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how timezones work. When you remove ["Zulu time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#History) (+00:00 offset, i.e. UTC) suffix from the string, the time *you provided* is used by the locale-aware system. This results in the time being displayed to be the same as the one provided:

| Offset | Raw Value | Locale-unaware | Locale-aware |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| +03:00 | `20210430T123000` | 2021-04-30 12:30:00 | 2021-04-30 12:30:00 |

If you keep the suffix, it means the time *you provided* is in the Universal Time Coordinated (or UTC) format. The time is then adjusted accordingly by the locale-aware system such as Google Calendar (provided the user did not disable timezone adjustment):

| Offset | Raw Value | Locale-unaware | Locale-aware |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| +03:00 | `20210430T123000Z` | 2021-04-30 12:30:00 | 2021-04-30 15:30:00 |

Next, the `YYYYMMDDTHHmmSSZ` is a valid Moment.js [format string](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), so should you plug it directly, the token semantics comes into play:

| Token | Repetitions | Meaning | Example |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Y | 4 | Long (4-digit) year format | 2021 |
| M | 2 | Short month format, padded to 2 digits if necessary | 01..12 |
| D | 2 | Day of Month format, padded to 2 digits if necessary | 01..31 |
| T | 1 | literal T, no special formatting meaning, so no need to escape | T |
| H | 2 | 24-hour hour format, padded to 2 digits if necessary | 00..23 |
| m | 2 | Minutes format, padded to 2 digits if necessary | 00..59 |
| S | 2 | Fractional seconds format | 00..99 |
| Z | 1 | Time Zone, sign + 4 digits without colon | +0000, -0000 |

As you can guess, the `YYYYMMDDTHHmmssZ` format string avoids the "fractional seconds" caveat, but leaves `Z` unescaped and thus treated as a timezone designator. This is solved by proper escaping, as per docs:

> To escape characters in format strings, you can wrap the characters in square brackets.

Try it for yourself (FYI, since you are using Moment.js, if you are not strictly forced to use it, don't, it is [officially deprecated](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/) in favour of other libraries until the [Temporal proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal/tree/main/docs) is shipped):

```js
(() => {
  const data = {
    location: "Calgary, Downtown",
    title: "The 2020 Festival"
  };

  const eventStartDateTime = new Date();
  const eventEndDateTime = new Date();

  const startDateTimeFormatted = moment(eventStartDateTime).format("YYYYMMDDTHHmmss[Z]");
  const endDateTimeFormatted = moment(eventEndDateTime).format("YYYYMMDDTHHmmss[Z]");

  const link = `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&dates=${startDateTimeFormatted}/${endDateTimeFormatted}&location=${data.location}&text=${data.title}`;

  const anchor = document.createElement("p");
  anchor.textContent = link;

  document.body.append(anchor);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @newdeveloper - NP, the "convert datetime to UTC" is likely to be the cause of confusion, they should've said that does not mean *adjust* (and using "format" is kinda wrong since Z is commonly understood as format string, not as literal suffix)